# get the file url from c# controller via jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a c# controller that returns a status file for the system. It prompts the user to open or download the file. The return type for the controller is actually System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.

I set up the route like this: /api/logging/status/{reqID}

If I goto the route directly in my web browser, http://mysite//api/logging/status/12345678, it works fine.

How can I get the URL to the file via jquery so that I can put that url in an achor tag like:

```
<a href="http://path.to.my.status.file/status.txt">Download Status</a>
```

Here is the controller:

```
[Route("/api/logging/status/{reqID}")]

    public IHttpActionResult GetStatus(Int32 reqID)
    {
        Stream stream;

            stream = new MemoryStream();

            var reqStatus = serializer.SerializeToString(req);
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqStatus);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "status.txt"));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: When you debug the server-side code, how does it fail?  Also, why are you using a different URL structure in the AJAX requests than in the manual request?  (In the AJAX you're using a query string parameter instead of putting the ID directly in the route.)

Comment: You can't download files using an ajax request.

Comment: Also, what code is retrieving the value for `reqID` from the US to send to the server?

Comment: @BenRobinson thanks, I'm not sure how to handle it, that's why I asked :)

Comment: @999cm999 There are libraries that fake it e.g. http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: @David thanks, my fault.  I fixed it.  It now does return the file in text format to the browser console.

Comment: @999cm999 The problem is you can't make the browser open a file download prompt from javascript, there is nothing useful you can do with the downloaded file unless you want to process it entirely in JavaScript.

Comment: @BenRobinson Ok I understand now. Thanks. What about getting the url to the file?  So I could just place it in an anchor tag in my html and let the browser handle it?  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok I edited the question to better reflect what I've learned so far in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried the following?

```
$.get('/api/logging/status/12345678', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

@999cm999,

It seems to me that you need another service method to serve the path to the txt file. You only have a method that serves the file itself as a download. That's how the browser example works.

However, if you want to insert the path to the txt file (http://path.to.my.status.file/status.txt) in an anchor tag of your HTML page, the method that you have does not fit. Create another method that returns the path to the file as a string. Then you can grab that and put it in the HREF attribute of your hyperlink element using jQuery or your favorite JS approach.

Let me know of your findings.